# Error al compilar aplicación en IOS con plugin de facebook en flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook

He intentado realizar la compilación de mi app en iOS la cual tiene el plugin de facebook instalado, obtengo el siguiente error:

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit": In Podfile: flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.3.1, which depends on FBSDKLoginKit (~> 7.1.0)

Comment: Qué versión tienes en el PodFile de FBSDKLoginKit?